# Where to ask about a deadlink to a particular line of source code?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was confused whether to ask it on Stack Overflow, or Programmers. [Python Chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) would have provided me the answer, but I thought it would be better to ask on a main site.

[This link](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Python/pythonrun.c#l763), which I provided in one of my answers, is dead (404). And I want to ask a question regarding that. For example, how do I recover it? I intended it to be a permalink, but it wasn't. Where do I get the permalink for a particular line of source code in [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial)?

On which site could I possibly ask such a question?

Comment: Not crawled by Wayback Machine... A bummer, indeed.

Comment: Nor google, nor corale (poked at it via http://cachedview.com/ )

Comment: ... that said, Programmers.SE isn't the right site to ask on either. This has nothing to do with conceptual, architectural, or design aspects of software engineering. You are best off asking the maintainers of the site. You may be able to get some information on web caches on Webapps.SE ( http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cached-webpages and http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cache ) though asking others do to the work for you of digging through these caches probably isn't a good question on any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @MichaelT it seems like a technical question, because I believe that link contains what appears to be the hash of the commit (the reason I picked it). IIrc, I spent a good deal of time finding that link when I wrote the answer because of the apparent hash code.

Comment: That it may be. It also isn't on topic on Programmers.SE. I suspect it is also off topic on Stack Overflow. You *might* get something better of an answer on WebApps *if* you are asking about caching and phrase it so it isn't asking someone to do the work for you. All that said, given the nature of the site (source code repo), I doubt they let any siders crawl it and the information, if stored anywhere, is on backups for the site.